# How to unblur the (user account) password entry page image in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, resolution, images, user-accounts

When I turn on my computer that is running Windows 10, or access a Windows 10 user account password entry page, I get an image of some cute wildlife or of a landscape as a sort of screen saver. Sometimes the image is normal, which I like, and sometimes it is deliberately blurred beyond recognition, and often I want to unblur it, but it is not so easy. I am puzzled as to why Windows 10 works like this. Sometimes my curiosity is so strong that I try restarting the computer, but this doesn't always solve the problem. I have Googled this a lot and found no reference to this problem.

So my question is, how to unblur the (user account) the password entry page image in Windows 10, or better still make it so all of them are sharp at all times.

Comment: [How to Disable the Login Screen’s Background Blur on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/426554/how-to-disable-the-login-screens-background-blur-on-windows-10/)

Answer (score 1):

You can install Winaero Tweaker https://winaero.com/winaero-tweaker it has a feature where you can disable the blur on the logon page.

Comment: The link provided expected results. OTOH, how trusted is this software? I'm worried about malware. Tried to upvote but don't have the required 15 rep.

Comment: @SecurityEveryDay - Please don't edit contributions to indicate you "attempted to upvote them" they will be rejected.  We already know you can't issue upvotes.

Comment: I was trying to edit my comment but accidentally edited the answer I was commenting on, and then I found I couldn't undo my mistake because the system said "No change detected" or words to that effect. So I added "Erroneous edit undone". Sorry for my errors.

Comment: @SecurityEveryDay It worked? or it didn't "How trusted is this software" Well i have the software on my computer and it works just fine, also you don't have to upvote you have to accept the anwser (using the green checkmark)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by changes in the registry:

Open in regedit the registry path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System`

Create a value of type `DWORD-Value (32-Bit)` and name it `DisableAcrylicBackgroundOnLogon` and set the value to `1`.

After a reboot the aero glass effect (the blur effect) should be gone.

Alternatively you can save the following data to a text file and change the file extension to `.reg`. Then double click it to import it into the registry.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System]
"DisableAcrylicBackgroundOnLogon"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Could I have a For Dummies type guide to how to do that? I heard it is risky to touch the registry if you are a noob/Dummy, like I am.

Comment: @SecurityEveryDay You can create a `.reg` file using the data I included in my answer and then simply double click it to import it.

Answer (score 0):

Click your way through start menu, settings, personalization, colors, and then toggle transparency effects to "off". No need to restart the computer.

I learned how to do it, having learned here from Robert that it is called "aero glass effect", by DuckDuckGoing "disable aero glass effect windows 10" and clicking on https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-transparency-effects-windows-10.